# Leaked window in android webview progress dialog

Tags: android, webview, progressdialog

I am getting leaked window due to progress dialog. Already tried progress.dismiss (one of given answer) upon finishing the loading of page. Couldnt figure out the reason of crash :/
If you get any idea, please share.

```
public class Webview3 extends Activity {
private WebView webView;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview2);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.test1);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Webview3.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    String url = "http://www.matrimonyphotography.com/testimonial.shtml";
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }
    else {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my error log which tells the area of problem are progressDialog.show(); and progressDialog.dismiss(); in onFinishedPage()

```
05-10 18:48:37.044 3470-3470/com.evolved.ayshir.picdrift E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.evolved.ayshir.picdrift.Webview has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{268317b8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                          at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                                          at com.evolved.ayshir.picdrift.Webview.onCreate(Webview.java:40)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
05-10 18:48:40.271 3470-3470/com.evolved.ayshir.picdrift E/AndroidRuntime:                                                                                                                                                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{268317b8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1026,348} not attached to window manager
                                                                           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:396)
                                                                           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:322)
                                                                           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
                                                                           at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:341)
                                                                           at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:324)
                                                                           at com.evolved.ayshir.picdrift.Webview$MyWebViewClient.onPageFinished(Webview.java:113)
                                                                           at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:524)
                                                                           at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:188)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had somewhat similar issue. I found out that under certain circumstances the boolean isShowing returns false even though dialog is showing. 
Try just checking if it's not null and calling dismiss on it. That worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

**First initalize**

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Webview3.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();
```

**and then put following code**

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.test1);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```